# Naming elements of matrix dimensions one at a time, when dimname is NULL

Tags: r

When dimnames is currently `NULL`, is it possible to re-name a matrix's dimestions one at a time?

For example, this fails:

```
mtx <- matrix(1:16,4)
dimnames(mtx)[[2]][1] <- 'col1'
```

with `Error in dimnames(mtx)[[2]][1] <- "col1" : 'dimnames' must be a list`

However this works:

```
mtx <- matrix(1:16,4)
dimnames(mtx)[[1]] <- letters[1:4]
dimnames(mtx)[[2]] <- LETTERS[1:4]
dimnames(mtx)[[2]][1] <- 'col1'
dimnames(mtx)[[2]][2] <- 'col2'
```

My objective is to seperately replace `dimnames(mtx)[[2]][1]` and `dimnames(mtx)[[2]][2]` etc ... if this is not possible, i can re-write the loop.

---

Thanks folks, I have ended up with the below -- I pass the names in via prepend:

```
mtxNameSticker <- function(mtx, prepend = NULL, MARGIN=2)
{
    if (MARGIN == 1) max <- nrow(mtx) else
        max  <- ncol(mtx)
    if (is.null(prepend)) if (MARGIN == 2) prepend <- 'C' else
        prepend <- 'R'
    if (length(prepend) == 1) prepend <- paste0(prepend, 1:dim(mtx)[[MARGIN]]) 
    dimnames(mtx)[[MARGIN]] <- seq(from=1, by=1, length.out=dim(mtx)[[MARGIN]]) 
    for (i in 1:max){
        dimnames(mtx)[[MARGIN]][i] <- prepend[i]
    }
    return(mtx)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For as long as `dimnames` is `NULL` and not an appropriate `list`, you cannot make assignments to it at particular positions. One easy way to create a dummy but complete list of `dimnames` is to run:

```
dimnames(mtx) <- lapply(dim(mtx), seq_len)
mtx
#   1 2  3  4
# 1 1 5  9 13
# 2 2 6 10 14
# 3 3 7 11 15
# 4 4 8 12 16
```

Then, you can make assignments *one at a time* like you were wishing:

```
dimnames(mtx)[[2]][1] <- 'col1'
mtx
#   col1 2  3  4
# 1    1 5  9 13
# 2    2 6 10 14
# 3    3 7 11 15
# 4    4 8 12 16
```

Comment: +1 / accepted. thanks v much. I want to the the dimensions seperately, so i'm going to go with: `dimnames(mtx)[[i]] <- seq(from=1, by=1, length.out=dim(mtx)[[i]])`.

Comment: @ricardo You can also use `seq_along(dim(mtx)[[i]])` instead of `seq(from=1, by=1, length.out=dim(mtx)[[i]])`.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning a *vector* even though you are asked to supply a list.

Try this:

```
R> M <- matrix(1:4,2,2)
R> M
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
R>
```

Columns:

```
R> M1 <- M; dimnames(M1) <- list(NULL, c("a","b")); M1
     a b
[1,] 1 3
[2,] 2 4
R>
```

Rows:

```
R> M2 <- M; dimnames(M2) <- list(c("A","B"), NULL); M2
  [,1] [,2]
A    1    3
B    2    4
R>
```

Comment: thanks that makes sense. I guess i was ambigious in my question -- i am aware that one may replace `dimnames(M2)[[1]]` and `dimnames(M2)[[2]]` seperately. by one at a time, i meant can i seperately replace `dimnames(M2)[[2]][1]` and `dimnames(M2)[[2]][2]` when `dimnames(M2)[[2]] == NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your comment. @DirkEddelbuettel is correct, you are assigning a vector to what should be a list.

The reason for this is that you are assigning dimnames when the dimnames are `NULL` (not assigned yet)

The way R evaluates the following

```
x <- NULL
x[[2]][1] <- 'col1'
str(x)
##  chr [1:2] NA "col1"
```

R returns  a vector of length 2, not a list of length 2.

For your assignment to work, `R` would have to evaluate

```
x <- NULL
x[[2]][1] <- 'col1'
str(x)
```

to give

```
## List of 2
## $ : NULL
## $ : chr "col1"
```

Which is what would happen if `x` was originally defined as `x <- list(NULL,NULL)`

however, the dimnames must be `NULL` or a list of appropriate length vectors

The following *does* work (and is really @flodel solution)

```
dimnames(mtx) <- list(character(nrow(mtx)), character(ncol(mtx)))
# or
# dimnames(mtx) <-  lapply(dim(mtx), character) 
dimnames(mtx)[[2]][1] <- 'col1'
```

Comment: +1. Okay, thanks. The bottom line is that flodel's neat hack is the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are allowed to set the name *of* the dimension without actually having any names *for* the dimension:

```
dimnames(mtx) = list(NULL,col1=NULL)
mtx
#      col1
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#  [1,]    1    5    9   13
#  [2,]    2    6   10   14
#  [3,]    3    7   11   15
#  [4,]    4    8   12   16
```